# autohotkey replacement rule with regex

Tags: regex, replace, autohotkey

I'd like to have an AHK replacement rule to replace

abc<some digits here>

to

cdeabc<the same digits>.

For example abc12345 to cdeabc12345.

Comment: Have you read the respective entries from the AHK docs, specifically [RegExReplace](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/RegExReplace.htm) and [RegEx Quick Reference](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm)? For the basic understanding of RegEx, there are tons of tutorials out there. Do you have any specific problems with the implementation? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The syntax of a replacement rule is ::btw::By the way. This means that if you type "btw" it will replace it with "By the way". What if I want to match btw234, where 234 can be any digits group, and replace it with "By the way 234", so the same digits group?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know autohotkey but this regex should do what you want

```
'abc123456456'.replace(/((abc)([0-9]+))/, "cde$1")
```

Comment: in AutoHotkey, it would be `output := RegExReplace("abc123456456", "((abc)([0-9]+))", "cde$1")`